# Gene Expression Profile Plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I'm trying to make Gene EXPRESSION PROFILE plot in R. My input data is a data frame where column 1 has gene names and next column2:18 are multiple cancer types. Here is a small set of data.

[image]

what I want is to make a graph that has samples on x-axis and from y=axis expression line of each gene.
something that looks like this.
[image]

but instead of timepoints on x-axis it should have Cancer types (columns)
so far I've tried ***ggplot()*** and ***geneprofiler()*** but i failed over and over.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ggplot` with `geom_line()` should work. What have you tried that failed?

Comment: hey, My data was in wide format so I was getting issues. Converting it to Long worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Data Format

The current format of the data is referred to as **wide format**, but `ggplot` requires **long format** data. The `tidyr` package (part of the `tidyverse`) has functions for converting between wide and long formats. In this case, you want the function [`tidyr::pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html). For example, if you have the data in a data.frame (or tibble) called `df_gene_expr`, the pivot would go something like

```
library(tidyverse)

df_gene_expr %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=2:18, names_to="cancer_type", values_to="gene_expr") %>%
  filter(ID == "ABCA8") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=cancer_type, y=gene_expr)) +
  geom_point()
```

where here we single out the one gene `"ABCA8"`. Change the `geom_point()` to whatever geometry you actually want (perhaps `geom_bar(stat='identity')`.

---

## Discrete Trendline

I'm not sure that `geom_smooth` is entirely appropriate - it is designed with continuous-continuous data in mind. Instead, I'd recommend `stat_summary`.

There's a slight trick to this because the discrete `cancer_type` on the x-axis. Namely, the `cancer_type` variable should be a `factor`, but we will use the underlying codes for the x-values in `stat_summary`. Otherwise, it would complain that using a `geom='line'` doesn't make sense.

Something along the lines:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x=cancer_type, y=gene_expr)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=4, color="red") +
  geom_line(aes(group=ID), size=0.5, alpha=0.3, color="black") +
  stat_summary(aes(x=as.numeric(cancer_type)), fun=mean, geom='line',
               size=2, color='orange')
```

**Output from Fake Data**
[image]

Technically, this same trick (`aes(x=as.numeric(cancer_type))`) could be equally-well applied to `geom_smooth`, but I think it still makes more sense to use the `stat_summary` which let's one explicitly pick the stat to be computed. For example, perhaps, `median` instead of `mean` might be more appropriate in this context for the summary function.

Comment: Converting wide to long format worked. one more thing can you help me withdrawing a TREND LINE. I've tried
`geom_smooth(size = 2, se = FALSE, color = "orange")`
but it shows me that 
**geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'**
with no trend line in the graph.